# How to get around Type mismatch Required: Foo<Type>, Found: Foo<Type?>

Tags: kotlin

Given the following Kotlin code:

```
class Foo<T>(val t : T?)

fun <T : Any, R : Any> Foo<T?>.transform(transformer : (T) -> R) : Foo<R?> {
  return when (t) {
    null -> Foo(null)
    else -> Foo(transformer(t))
  }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  val foo = Foo(args.firstOrNull())

  val bar = foo.transform<String, Int> { t -> t.length }

  val baz = bar.transform<Int, IntRange> { t -> t..(t + 1) }
}
```

Why do I get the following error:
`Type mismatch. Required: Foo<String?> Found: Foo<String>`

If I remove the `?` from the extension function to be `Foo<T>.transform` I instead get the following error: 
`Type mismatch. Required: Foo<Int> Found: Foo<Int?>`

I can understand the second error, because you cannot assign `Int?` to `Int`, but the first doesn't make any sense, as you can assign `String` to `String?`

EDIT:

I have modified the `class Foo<T>` to be `class Foo<out T>` and this works for me as the value `t` will only ever be read after the initial assignment. With this option I do not need to define the type parameters at the call site of `transform`.

Another option I have found that I think is a bit messy (and not sure why it makes a difference) is adding a third type parameter to the extension function as follows:

```
fun <T : Any, U : T?, R : Any> Foo<U>.transform(transformer : (T) -> R) : Foo<R?>
```

The call site of this on the other hand I find a bit odd. Looking at the above code the call of `foo.transform` **MUST NOT** include the type parameters, but the call of `bar.transform<Int, Int?, IntRange>` **MUST** include the type parameters in order to work.

This option allows setting the value `t` at some later point if it were a `var` instead of `val`. But it also removes the smart casting on `t` in the `transform` function. Although that can be gotten around with a `!!` if you are not worried about race conditions or (with some additional effort) `?:` or `?.` if you are worried about race conditions.

Comment: I think it's the same reason why arrays should be invariant. You assign (so you have an object of type `Foo<String>`), and then you'll try to write `null` instead of your value `t`, and compiler checks will no longer save you (since the compiler sees `Foo<String?>`).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `Foo<T>` class to be *not* invariant (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html):

```
class Foo<out T>(val t : T?)

fun <T : Any, R : Any> Foo<T?>.transform(transformer : (T) -> R) : Foo<R?> {
  return when (t) {
    null -> Foo(null)
    else -> Foo(transformer(t))
  }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  val foo = Foo(args.firstOrNull())

  val bar = foo.transform<String, Int> { t -> t.length }

  val baz = bar.transform<Int, IntRange> { t -> t..(t + 1) }
}
```

The `out T` specifies precisely the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify the property `t` in the constructor as `T?` you don't need to specify `Foo<T?>` as receiver and `Foo<R?>` as return type. Instead use `Foo<T>` and `Foo<R>` and it will work.

```
class Foo<T>(val t : T?)

fun <T: Any, R: Any> Foo<T>.transform(transformer : (T) -> R) : Foo<R> {
    return when (t) {
        null -> Foo(null)
        else -> Foo(transformer(t))
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val foo = Foo(args.firstOrNull())
    val bar = foo.transform { t -> t.length }
    val baz = bar.transform { t -> t..(t + 1) }
}
```

**Note:** You don't need to specify the generic types for transform because they can be inferred (at least in this example).